# Angular 2 resolve for parent route

Tags: javascript, angular

I have this code.

Route 'new' this child route for 'users'.
Route 'users' has resolver.
This work fine.

But after success create user.
I redirect to 'users', but new user not display in list, because
DataResolver not work after redirect from child route.

How Can i fix it?

```js
//Roiting
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: 'dashboard',
    component: Dashboard,

    children: [
      { path: 'users',
        component: Users,
        resolve: {
          users: DataResolver
        },
        children: [
          { path: 'new', component: NewUser }
        ]
      },
    ]
  }
];


//Resolver
@Injectable()
export class DataResolver implements Resolve<any> {
  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> {
    return this.userService.all(); // return users
  }
}


//Component
export class NewUser {
  errorMessage: string;
  user: User;

  constructor(public route: ActivatedRoute,
              private userService: UserService,
              private router: Router) {
    this.user = new User();
  }

  onSubmit(): void {
    this.userService
        .createUser(this.user)
        .subscribe(
          user  => {
            this.router.navigate(['/dashboard', 'users']);
          },
          error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
  }
}
```

```js
// USers component
export class Users implements OnInit {
  users: User[];

  constructor(public route: ActivatedRoute,
              private router: Router) {
    this.route.data.subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.users = data.users;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your 'Users' component should be like this, I assume you return `User[]` type from your web service;

```
export class Users {
     users;
     constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute, ...){
          _route.data.subscribe((wrapper: {res: any[] }) => {
               this.users = <User[]>wrapper.res;
          });
     }
}
```

When your link is `.../dashboard/user`, it gets users via resolver and wrap it. I just call it as `wrapper`, you can give another name. Just know that after resolving, it wraps the response from your service.

Please let me know if you need more information.

Edit 1:

Here is how I use resolver, I hope it helps

```
//app.route
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'user',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'user',
        loadChildren: '.../user.module#UserModule'
    }
];

const rootRoutes: Routes = [
    ...appRoutes
];

export const appRouting = RouterModule.forRoot(rootRoutes, { useHash: true });

//user.route
const userRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: UserComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'create',
                component: UserCreateComponent
            },
            {
                path: '',
                component: UserListComponent,
                resolve: {
                    res: UserResolver
                }
            }
        ]
    }
];

export const userRouting = RouterModule.forChild(userRoutes);

//user.module
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        userRouting,
        FormsModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        UserComponent,
        UserCreateComponent,
        UserListComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        UserService,
        UserResolver
    ]
})

export class UserModule { }

//user.resolver
export class UserResolver implements Resolve<any>{
    constructor(private service: UserService) { }

    public resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> {
       return this.service.get();//return all users
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes my Users component be like this.

(I'm update question)

Comment: Yes.
The problem is that the resolver does not work in the transition from child router.

Comment: I updated the answer, I am not using routing like the way you use. Maybe it helps.